# What action should be taken on a question that is an answer?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a *question* that ran (my paraphrase):

> I wanted to answer [this question X](http://example.com) but it was closed, so I couldn't answer it. I thought I'd post my answer up here: (some code that I probably would have downvoted because it wasn't even a reasonable answer to the closed question).

So we thus had an answer of dubious quality posted as a question, with the only thing relating the two being a hyperlink in the body of the problem question…

I originally began looking into whether to flag it as VLQ, but while I was deciding a gold badge holder closed it as a duplicate of that question X the OP had said they wanted to answer, which reduced my flagging options to rude, abusive or moderator. I was somewhat on the fence as to whether to flag it for moderator review, because I wasn't sure dealing with it was worth their time, but I also wasn't sure what other options there were for dealing with something that is as nonsense as posting a poor answer as a question, other than voting to reopen it and then re-flagging; that also seems like a sub-optimal approach for various reasons.

I wasn't entirely surprised that the flag was declined, though the given reason of "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" seems quite tautological on an "in need of moderator intervention" flag… :)

As it is, it looks like the community is pushing towards the action I thought a moderator might have taken - the question's attracted sufficient downvotes for delete votes to start being cast…

I don't expect I'll come across this again soon, but is the sensible approach for "answer posted as question" to downvote, bookmark, check later to see if delete votes can be cast?

Comment: Close as "Needs details or clarity", as with any other question posts containing a solution.

Comment: I think I disagree with your custom flag being declined. This is a clear case of a user abusing the system, trying to work around system-imposed limitations, and that's something which should be handled by a moderator. This is a rather different (and unusual) case. The more typical case is where a confused user posts an answer as a question. That doesn't need moderator intervention; it just needs to be closed. But this particular case is something quite a bit more intentional and admitted to by the author.

Comment: +1 for the sentence including the word "tautological".  Even better, using it in a sentence that starts with "I wasn't entirely surprised that the flag was declined,...".

Comment: If this were a self-answered question, I might have defended it as legitimate.  It’s hard to judge without context.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm interested to know why you think a moderator should waste their time on this, when it's already been handled via the close/delete hammer? A user who knows the rules and doesn't care enough about them to break them isn't going to be deterred from breaking them in future via a talking-to, and a suspension is probably not Be Nice.

Comment: @IanKemp That's what moderators do: deal with users who break the rules.

Answer (score 15):

Questions on Stack Overflow need to ask a question, or at least pose a clear problem for us to solve for OP. If they don't do that, then you can close the question as unclear, or formally "Needs details or clarity". Alternatively you can use a custom close reason and explain in your own words what the issue is and how OP can resolve it.

Comment: None of the flags we have match the given condition. I would prefer using the custom flag here.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him There is a difference between flagging and voting to close (requires 3000 reputation).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Close voting allows a custom reason, though, so the comment's intention still applies.

Comment: I just want to point out that answering someone's own question is OK though, although I understand it is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Cast a delete vote as soon as the option is available. The most important thing about trash is taking it out, not which of several functionally identical cans it was thrown in. We all know this is trash, so wringing your hands over the exact category of trash it belongs to is a waste of your time and energy. (Usually. I do have a problem with wrongly categorizing something as bigotry or whatever social justice term of the week, but that's because it drums up mobs and leads to poor treatment of users by staff and moderators. In other words, actual consequences that matter, and that's not the case here.)

In general, such an obvious violation of the rules warrants closure. If you don't feel good about leveraging gold-badge hammer powers (which helps clean up the mess much more quickly), using a custom reason to say it's not even a question is fine.

Comment: I have to disagree that _"wringing your hands over the exact category of trash it belongs to is a waste of your time and energy"_. If there really is no appropriate category then provide a custom response. Why does this matter? Because inappropriate (or missing) categorization can come back to haunt you when performing data analysis, and lead to wrong conclusions. For example, I see lame-but-valid questions incorrectly being closed because there was obviously no research effort made, or they were not useful, yet you will not (cannot) know that from reviewing the close reasons.

Comment: @skomisa Data analysis on something as subjective as content rating is bunk to begin with. It's a total waste of time when the data is merely opinion. If you're going to do data analysis, work with objective measurements. And even then, it's invalid to use data analysis to prove a claim or relationship; any number of coincidences or correlations with third factors can lead to dramatically wrong conclusions if you try. You have to stick with using it to disprove (or fail to disprove) hypotheses.

Comment: The closure reason matters, if for no other reason than to tell the OP what went wrong.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with the spirit of the comments here, that the categorization _does_ matter a lot of the time (eg. for defense of the action later, for giving proper messaging to OP, etc.), but for this particular case, where OP clearly understood they were abusing the system (and admitted to as much), I think this is fine. The problem with the "garbage is garbage" approach comes when the trash is borderline, or we disagree about it being trash– that isn't true for this case.

Comment: @PasserBy Please stop ignoring the context. The OP knew what went wrong **before they posted the question** (because they knew they weren't supposed to post it), so you're suggesting that we need to tell them what they already know. Which helps a grand total of nobody, while also managing to waste time.

Comment: @IanKemp I disagree. Judging by the words, it could be that OP is gaming the system, but it also might be that OP is either unsure or unaware of what a closure signifies. Clearly, they don't know enough about the site. If you want to hand out a suspension, _you still have to explain it to the OP_.